# How to set default value for parameter in bash_aliases

Tags: 18.04, bash

I have the following function. When i run this I get error `Default Message command not found`.

```
commit {
    ${1:-Default Message}
    echo "git add ."
    git commit -m '$1'
}
```

I just wan't to set default string value in the last command if no parameter is provided.

This is how I intend to use the function in terminal:

`commit`
result should be: `git commit -m 'Default Message'`

`commit some random message`
result should be: `git commit -m 'some random message'`

Please guide.

Comment: I followed a post where it showed how to set default parameter and the syntax was `${1:-foo}` like so, but What you mention is to check if a parameter is passed or null using condition. I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: You should assign it to a local shell variable and then use that variable in the `git` command line instead of `$1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some issues here:

- A function definition in bash needs `()` after the function's name
- `${1:-Default Message}` *returns* either the content of `$1` (if that is given)
  *or* the given default value. Note: it *returns* it. That is, it is the same
  as if you had written:

  ```
  if [ -n "$1" ]; then
      $1
  else
      Default Message
  fi
  ```

  bash is dumb, so it will try to simply run "Default Message" as a command.
  Obviously, there is no such command, hence your error message.
- The last line (`git commit -m '$1'`) will use the literal `$1` (read: dollar-one)
  as the commit message because single quotes were used and they don't expand variables
  inside them.

Try this instead:

```
commit() {
    msg="${1:-Default Message}"
    echo "git add ."
    git commit -m "$msg"
}
```

Or:

```
commit() {
    echo "git add ."
    git commit -m "${1:-Default Message}"
}
```

Comment: FWIW; `function { ... }` also works.

Comment: @Hannu You mean `function commit() {…}`? Then _yes_. And actually I do that in my private files. But I somewhere read that it is be deprecated or discouraged or something.

Comment: Yes, I meant `function name { }` - typing faster than thinking. If it is *deprecated or discouraged* it would be better to have that defined as from the source, without the "hearsay" type statement.

Comment: @Hannu Agreed. I cannot (and don't desire to) find a source right now. The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions) basically says _either_ `function name {…}` _or_ `function name() {…}` _or_ `name() {…}` and doesn't mention any deprecation warnings. So be it. I'll keep using `function name()` until it breaks!

Comment: Thanks for the input, I was unaware of the quotation marks. And yes this solved ,y problem,. many thanks